# I succesfully uploaded the file to heroku and it went online but the commands were not working

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

I uploaded this file to heroku and it uploaded without any errors and it successfully went online but none of the commands were working.

The code is:

```
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready.')

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Pong! {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms')

@client.command()
async def bye(ctx):
    bye = ['Bye-eth', 
           'Bye puta',
           'See ya later']
    await ctx.send(f'{random.choice(bye)}')

@client.command(aliases = ['hoi', 'hola', 'hi', 'hey', 'bonjour'])
async def hello(ctx):
    hey = ['hola puta', 
           'hello friend',
           "how ya doin'", 
           "What's up", 
           "Heyy",
           'Helo']
    await ctx.send(f'{random.choice(hey)}\nhttps://tenor.com/view/hello-gif-9499692')


@client.command()
async def say(ctx, *, string):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
    await ctx.send(string)



@client.command(aliases = ['8ball'])
async def _8ball(ctx, *, question):
    responses = ['It is certain.', 
                 'It is decidedly so.',
                 'Without a doubt.',
                 'Yes – definitely', 
                 'You may rely on it.', 
                 'As I see it, yes.', 
                 'Most likely.',
                 'Outlook good.',
                 'Yes.', 
                 'Signs point to yes.'  , 
                 'Reply hazy, try again.', 
                 'Ask again later.', 
                 'Better not tell you now.', 
                 'Cannot predict now.', 
                 'Concentrate and ask again.', 
                 "Don't count on it.", 
                 'My reply is no.', 
                 'My sources say no.', 
                 'Outlook not so good.', 
                 'Very doubtful.']
    await ctx.send(f'Question: {question}\nAnswer: {random.choice(responses)}')



@client.command()
async def thank(ctx, *, member):
    await ctx.send(f'thank you {member} :grin:')


@client.command()
async def welcome(ctx, *, member):
    await ctx.send(f'ur welcome {member} :grin:')


@client.command()
async def kill(ctx, *, member):
    await ctx.send(f'oof {member} has been killed :gun:')





client.run('NzExNTQwNzI5OTM1Mjk4NTcw.XsEgTw.HiEuDqPZjsCOxgk3dajkQZcc1Bg')
```

The Procfile is: `worker python puta.py`

The requirement is: `discord.py==0.16.12`

I think that i need to add random in the requirements list too but i don't know how to write it... i tried to write it as `random` but it was giving an error.

Can someone please help me with this; any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

`discord.py==0.16.12` is an older version of `discord.py` that uses `client.send_message` instead of `ctx.send`. If you want your current code to work, you need to use a newer version of `discord.py` on your Heroku instance.

As of this post, the latest version of `discord.py` is `1.3.3`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with this is your requirement for `discord.py`. 0.16.12 isn't the version that your discord bot is made to work in. Try removing the `==0.16.12` and it should automatically install the most up-to-date version.

Comment: No worries! Don't forget to mark the answer as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped you, as it will let others with the same problem find the solution faster! Good luck with the bot :)

Answer (score 0):

I see others have already answered your question here. But I want to add something very important for you. You just posted your code with your token inside of it online. I recommend you to regenerate your token now before anyone abuses your bot.

Comment: Discord has a system in place where it automatically regenerates a bot's token if it's leaked online - they send you a DM [like so](https://imgur.com/a/TuuAe9e).